# jboss 7 standalon-full.xml as config

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I want to start `JBoss AS v7` and set `standalone-full.xml` as default config. In my `standalone.conf` I put this line:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml"`.

But when I start server, it take `standalone.xml` as config. My OS is Win7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For windows, you need to edit `standalone.conf.bat`. `standalone.conf` is for linux/unix environments.

Answer (score 17):

You can configure **JBoss to start** using **standalone-full.xml** from **Eclipse** using below steps :-

**Locate JBoss Server from Eclipse Server Tab :-**

[image: JBoss Server In Eclipse Server Tab]

**Double click on server to open JBoss Runtime Server Configuration :-**

[image: JBoss Runtime Configuration]

**Now, Click on Runtime Environment link to open below dialog which allows to edit Jboss Server Runtime Configuration :-**

[image: Edit JBoss Configuration]

Click on **Browse** button to locate **standalone-full.xml** & save the configuration. Start JBoss server from Eclipse, it will use full profile defined in **standalone-full.xml** to start.

Comment: Just to note, AFAIK this does not apply for standard Eclipse installation but Eclipse + JBoss Tools

Answer (score 11):

Edit **jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat** and change

**From**

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"
```

**To**

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml"
```

OR

Once can simply use below command to start the server form command prompt.

```
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml
```