# Configuring/injecting a JMS connection factory and a topic in WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, jndi, wildfly

I'd like to do some experiments with JMS on jBoss WildFly 8.2.

The default WildFly `standalone-full.xml` configuration file has the following fragments:

```xml
<hornetq-server>

    <connectors>
        ...
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
    </connectors>

        ...

    <jms-connection-factories>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
            <connectors>
                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
            </connectors>
            <entries>
                <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
            </entries>
        </connection-factory>
        ...
    </jms-connection-factories>

    <jms-destinations>
         <!-- this destination I have added myself as I need a "topic", but 
                the default configuration has only two preconfigured "queues". -->
        <jms-topic name="MyTestTopic">
            <entry name="java:/jms/topic/MyTestTopic"/>
        </jms-topic>
    </jms-destinations>

</hornetq-server>
```

I am trying to inject this connection factory and this topic into an EJB in the following way:

```java
@Stateless
public class JmsPublisher {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/topic/MyTestTopic")
    Topic topic;
```

But I get the following error message at deployment:

```
Operation ("deploy") failed ... Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ...

...JmsPublisher\".jmsConnectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.ConnectionFactory]"
...JmsPublisher\".topic is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jms.topic.MyTestTopic]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You should inject your destinations/connection factories using `mappedName`, and you may want to consider the JMS 2.0 new APIs - `JMSContext`

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/topic/someTopic")
private Topic topic;
```

Assuming you have an entry like this

```
<jms-topic name="someTopic">
 <entry name="topic/someTopic"/>
</jms-topic>
```

For connection factories, it's recommended to use the default injection point

```
@Resource
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

but even better, just use `@Inject JMSContext context` and send messages using it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I do use `mappedName` in my injections. I think that the first two code fragments in your response are identical to the code I use. Are not they?

Comment: My topic definition is different than yours.

Comment: I tried your code. I still have the same error for the `topic` field. The error for the `connectionFactory` field is gone. Probably something got injected there .

Comment: When you say code, you mean the descriptor change? Pl update your question to clarify.

Comment: I updated the XML (in `standalone-full.xml`) and my Java code. I copied all three snippets from your answer and tried to deploy. If you need any more information in my question, please say what you want to see.

Comment: John, I would not like to update my question with the changes that you have suggested because I will either have to replace my own code snippets or create a question that is exceedingly long.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702185/3827696), `standalone.xml` supports Java EE Web-Profile plus some extensions, `standalone-full.xml` supports Java EE Full-Profile.

My problem  was that I defined the JMS connection factory and the JMS topic in `standalone-full.xml`. jBoss WildFly uses `standalone.xml` by default.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158437/3827696) explain how to configure WildFly to use `standalone-full.xml` instead of `standalone.xml`. Switching to `standalone-full.xml` solved my problem.